# HTC one X keeps restarting on Connecting to the Wifi

Tags: reboot, htc-one-x

Hi I am using Htc One X - Android version 4.1.1 from atnt. However in the last few days my phone keeps rebooting as soon as I try and connect to the wifi. If at all it does connect I have to kill all my applications asap to make sure it works fine. 
On opening any app like whatsapp or facebook it will show unforunately "the app name" has stopped working and it will again reboot.

Similarly while trying to uninstalling Facebook/Twitter it will do the same thing while if I uninstall any other apps like any launcher/ yelp etc it uninstalls perfectly. Please advise what is wrong ?

Comment: Have you rooted your device? Is it running stock firmware? Have you installed any pirated apps? Would you consider a factory reset? Do you have an SD card, could it be at the end of its life?

Comment: No device isnt rooted. Yes it is running stock firmware. No Pirated Apps have been installed. As in htc one x sd card is inbuilt how can I say if it is nearing the end ?

Comment: Sorry, thought the One X had a micro SD card also (it doesn't obviously). You could replace it or use it a different device. I'm reluctant to recommend a factory reset as you'll have to reinstall everything. Would you be able to install ADB or the Android SDK and pull a log of the errors? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36574/settings-hangs-when-scanning-for-wifi-since-jb-update-on-one-x?rq=1 you could try this, I know it's a different crashing, but maybe it's related? Worth a shot as it will only take 2 mins.

Comment: I am not aware of the process of pulling out error logs. I wouldnt mind a reset though. Is it a software issue for sure or could it be a hardware one ?

Comment: Try changing your WiFi settings to those in the link: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36574/settings-hangs-when-scanning-for-wifi-since-jb-update-on-one-x?rq=1 and see if it helps, it can't hurt at all. There's no way for me to tell if it's hardware or software but my hunch is software since some apps are fine, but there could be 2 issues here: WiFi issue, Uninstalling apps issue. Factory reset is a bit of a Nuclear Option but if you know your passwords and everything you NEED is backed up you could do it. But I'll keep looking into it in the meantime before you do that.

Comment: Yes but I read somewhere that it could be a logic board issue and I was not sure. Could it be that? because most of the applications run fine when I am not connected like games etc as soon as I am on a wireless network the phone restarts. Facebook wont unistall wont update wont open just reboots the system . can i be a logic board issue ?

Comment: It could well be, as I said I don't know, but we can't do anything to fix hardware so I guess trying the software route is a good start. If it is hardware then you'll need it repaired.

Comment: alright. Ill wait for a while if there is nothing concrete I might as well go with a reset. Thanks